# How to query MySQL ignoring particular characters

Tags: mysql

In a database I have something like this "something (something_else)",
is it possible using a "LIKE" query for you to query and get aforementioned to result when querying the database with "something something_else" (so without the "()" characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace on the criteria and the field to remove the characters. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '(', ''), ')', '') 
    LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE('something something_else', '(', ''), ')', '')
```